# Component "loop" with React JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, reactjs

I'am studying React JS library, and i wish create a "loop" of component, returning array values from json file. Here my json file:

```
{
  "data": {
    "children": [{
      "data": {
        "score": 4
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "score": 2
        }
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

My react component:

```
var ImagesList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      var imagesNodes = this.props.data.map(function (image){
        return (
          <div className="card">
              <p>{image.score} </p>
          </div>
        );
      });

      return (
        <div className="images">
          {imagesNodes}
        </div>
      );
    }
  });

var ImageBox = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
      return {
        data: {children:[]}
      };
    },

    getImages: function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: this.props.url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
          this.setState({data: data});
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err){
          console.error(url, status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
      });
    },

  componentWillMount: function(){
      this.getImages();
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="list-images">
          {<ImagesList data={this.state.data.children}/>}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

  React.render(
    <ImageBox url="myfile.json" />,
    document.getElementById('test')
  );
```

When I run the code, returning this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

I dont know how to fix that.

Comment: do you get the same error if don't call getImages on component will mount? of not, then the returning data structure is off on the re-rendering

Comment: @Fernando - Did the solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

JSON input data seems to be invalid. Validated it on [JSONParser](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

`ImageList` component expects `children` JSON Array inside the `data` object. So if AJAX call returns following JSON, component would be able to render that data

```
{
  "children": [
    {
      "score": 4
    },
    {
      "score": 2
    }
  ]
};
```

Please note that  `this.setState({data: data});` is already having `data` variable. So the response should not again set `data` else it becomes `data.data.children`. That is why code is throwing `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.`

For further reading after you complete ReactJS study, I would recommend to check [Flux Architecture](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html), which is recommended way of implementing ReactJS applications

Answer (score 0):

Lets debug your code. in the ajax callback function at your code. you gets the json data returns and you set the state data with the return data. So this.state.data will be:

```
{
  "data": {
    "children": [{
      "data": {
        "score": 4
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "score": 2
        }
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

And in the render method you are trying to insert props to ImagesList from ImageBox as

```
data = { this.state.data.children }
```

but `this.state.data.children` is undefined. there is no key named children in this.state.data. You can do

```
 {<ImagesList data={this.state.data.data.children}/>}
```

NB. Dont forget to validate the JSON value as described in above comment and Parse it to Json.

```
 getImages: function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: this.props.url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
      this.setState({data: JSON.parse(data)});
    }.bind(this),
    error: function(xhr, status, err){
      console.error(url, status, err.toString());
    }.bind(this)
  });
},
```